# Centering Logo Without Overlapping Nav Menu

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, centering

My site uses a navigation menu that stays aligned left. I would like to add a logo to the nav bar that stays centered, but doesn't overlap with my menu when the screen size is reduced.

Couldn't find any resources that were helpful, so here's my current code minus styling:

```
<nav>
    <div class="menu">
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <a href="#">3</a>
        <a href="#">4</a>
    </div>
    <div class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png"></a></div>
</nav>

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.menu {
    margin-right: auto;
}

.menu div {
    display: inline-block;
}

.logo{
    position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    top: -41px;
    max-width: 160px;
    height: 37px;
}
```

Comment: I think I will be able to help you, but I will need to see the CSS code aswell, as the positioning of the logo will probably be done with CSS. /Zphex

Comment: Centered vertically or horizontally?

Comment: Horizontally. I can figure out vertically for whatever solution, but I can't get anything that would work like a "min-margin-left".

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these solutions, depending on what you want to accomplish:

```
.menu, .logo {
    float: left;
}
```

or

```
.menu {
    float: left;
}
.logo {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for the logo to be centered, not float right or left. :/

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the CSS for your logo , So you dis not the it where to get positioned .I think that must be your Major problem .

Comment: Astute observation! I overlooked the logo styling. It's added now.